# Unity - How to force a next Input?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am coding a battle menu, it has a character selection panel and a sub menu panel, you need to press enter to move from each menu to the next, however it is skipping going to the sub menu and goes straight into enemy selection, I believe this is because my code is keeping the input, so is there any way to force it to go to the next input and discard the value it currently has.

```c#
public void CursorControl()
{
    if (CharacterSelectActive == true)
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Return))
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < (CursorPosition); i++)
            {
                MovesPanelCursor.transform.Translate(42f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
            }
            CursorPosition = 0;

            PanelSwitch();
        }
    }
    if (MoveSelectActive == true)
    {


        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Escape))
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < (CursorPosition); i++)
            {
                MovesPanelCursor.transform.Translate(42f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
            }
            CursorPosition = 0;
            PanelSwitch();
        }
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.S))
        {
            CursorPosition = CursorPosition + 1;
            MovesPanelCursor.transform.Translate(-42f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
            Debug.Log(CursorPosition);
            if (CursorPosition > 3)
            {
                MovesPanelCursor.transform.Translate(42f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
                CursorPosition = 3;
            }
        }
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.W))
        {
            CursorPosition = CursorPosition - 1;
            MovesPanelCursor.transform.Translate(42f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
            Debug.Log(CursorPosition);
            if (CursorPosition < 0)
            {
                MovesPanelCursor.transform.Translate(-42f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
                CursorPosition = 0;
            }
        }

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Return))
        {
                if (CursorPosition == 0 || CursorPosition == -1)
                {
                    Attack();
                }
                if (CursorPosition == 1)
                {

                }
                if (CursorPosition == 2)
                {

                }
                if (CursorPosition == 3 || CursorPosition == 4)
                {

                }
            }
        }

public void PanelSwitch()
{
    CharacterPanel.SetActive(true);
    MoveSelectActive = !MoveSelectActive;
    MovesPanel.SetActive(MoveSelectActive);


}
```

Comment: your retun key just has a bunch of if statements for Attack() how are you using it to switch panels?

Comment: Using my PanelSwitch method.

Comment: Small coding tip - if you're checking the value of a boolean in an if statement you don't need to write "== true".

Answer (score 1):

can you please provide your code?... -.-
if you are detecting the enter key using

```
if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Enter))
{
    // move to next menu
}
```

when the enter key is pressed, it will be pressed more then one game-frame, so basically it will go to your sub-menu and there immediately jump to the next menu without you being the step in-between because that submenu also detected a pressed enter-key

try using

```
if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Enter))
{
    // move to next menu
}
```

"down" instead

Edit:
If "PanelSwitch();" internally invokes the CursorControl(), be aware that the same input still holds. In that case it's better to just set the MoveSelectActive or what ever and wait for the next frame Update() to reinvade the controller

Edit:

Varialbes such as MoveSelectActive are quite intransparent in your post, I can't understand what they are initialised with, and how the change of state caused in PanelSwitch() affects the user's options in the UI and what they are meant to cause in the flow of the following CursorControl().

As a hint, I would start to find an issue with the flow, not in getting the keyboard inputs. I don't quite understand what you mean with "force the next input", maybe if you can clarify that I'd understand that there is more to it

Comment: what does PanelSwitch(); do?
please post it

Comment: are you sure you want it to be possible that both "if (CharacterSelectActive == true)" and "if (MoveSelectActive == true)" can be executed?, otherwise you'll need an else, or an early return